# Função. Linguagem C

Tags: c

Boa noite, estou fazendo um exercicio de função, onde eu digito dois numeros e escolho qual operação eu quero fazer, 1 ele aplica a função soma e 2 a função subtração, mas meu algoritmo não está funcionando e gostaria de saber o que estou fazendo de errado =s segue o algoritmo

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int somanumero(int numero1, int numero2){
    int result;
    result = numero1 +numero2;
    return result; 
}

int subnumero (int numero1, int numero2){
    int result;
    result = numero1 - numero2;
    return result;
}

int main (){
    int n1,n2,resp,result;
    result = 0;
    printf ("\nDigite o primeiro numero: ");
    scanf ("%d", &n1);
    printf ("\nDigite o segunto numero: ");
    scanf ("%d", &n2);
    printf ("\nQual operação gostaria de fazer. Soma [1] Sub [2]");
    scanf ("%d", resp);
    if (resp = 1){
        result = somanumero(n1,n2);
    }
    else {
        result = subnumero (n1,n2);
    }
    printf ("O resultado da equação é: %d", result);
}
```

Comment: Em vez de `if (resp = 1)`, tem que ser `if (resp == 1)` - o operador `=` atribui o valor, e como 1 é considerado "true", sempre entra no `if`. Já o operador `==` faz a comparação corretamente

Answer (score 0):

Pude observar que faltava o `&` no terceiro `scanf` (`resp`) e também um erro na condição da operação.

Fiz estes ajustes e diminui um pouco o código, ficou assim:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int somanumero(int numero1, int numero2){
    return numero1 + numero2;
}

int subnumero (int numero1, int numero2){
    return numero1 - numero2;
}

int main (){
    int n1,n2,resp,result = 0;
    
    printf ("\nDigite o primeiro numero: ");
    scanf ("%d", &n1);
    
    printf ("\nDigite o segunto numero: ");
    scanf ("%d", &n2);
    
    printf ("\nQual operação gostaria de fazer. Soma [1] Sub [2]");
    scanf ("%d", &resp);
    
    if (resp == 1){
        result = somanumero(n1,n2);
    } else {
        result = subnumero (n1,n2);
    }
    
    printf ("O resultado da equação é: %d", result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

É bem provável que tenha estudado algoritmos antes de ir para programação
e lá usávamos o receba como uma seta (<-)
basta lembrar que em grande parte das linguagens o receba é um sinal de igual simples
ou seja
se quer verificar se x é igual a y seria x==y
fora isso só faltou o "&" no terceiro scan
Boa sorte com os estudos

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int somanumero(int numero1, int numero2){
    int result;
    result = numero1 +numero2;
    return result; 
}

int subnumero (int numero1, int numero2){
    int result;
    result = numero1 - numero2;
    return result;
}

int main (){
    int n1,n2,resp,result;
    result = 0;
    printf ("\nDigite o primeiro numero: ");
    scanf ("%d", &n1);
    printf ("\nDigite o segunto numero: ");
    scanf ("%d", &n2);
    printf ("\nQual operação gostaria de fazer. Soma [1] Sub [2]");
    scanf ("%d", &resp);
    if (resp == 1){
        result = somanumero(n1,n2);
    }
    else {
        result = subnumero (n1,n2);
    }
    printf ("O resultado da equação é: %d", result);
}
```